# Redirect python tracebacks through Pygments

Tags: python, bash, unix, pygments

My application is invoked from `run.py`. I've installed Pygments and I'd like to redirect Python's output so that as tracebacks occur, they're formatted in an easier to read format.

This is the command that I've tried, `python run.py 2>&1 | pygmentize -l py`

Redirecting both `stdout` and `stderr` through pygmentize. The pygmentize documentation says that it will read from `stdin` if no file is provided, "If no input file is given, use stdin, if -o is not given, use stdout."

However, when I redirect like this, no output--errors or log statements or anything else--is output to my terminal.

When I run my command without piping its output into pygmentize, i.e. `python run.py 2>&1` I get this output:

```
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with reloader
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's strange. When I try your example, it works fine. (I forced a traceback, and it is pygmentized properly.) Can you show us the output of `python run.py 2>&1` (without the pipe to pygmentize)?

Comment: @btanaka when I do that I do get output. I updated my question with that test and its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pygmentize [reads the whole input stream](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/2479eb54f22b68940a94d3ee9e10aef7a9877488/pygments/cmdline.py?at=default#cl-403) when reading from stdin and only outputs everything if the input stream is closed, so you only will get any output piped through pygments after your first process has ended.

I'm afraid there's little you can do about that. If you want to format a continuous stream, You could only try to write your own wrapper around pygments wich reads the input stream in chunks and feeds that to pygments.

The reason why you don't see any output at all now is that you're probably using <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to stop your process in the shell, but that kills both processes. If you use `kill` to only terminate the server process, then you should see at least the lines you mentioned above going through pygments.